# How do I connect 4 tables in Laravel 7?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

So basically I have 4 tables

[image]

The **employees**, **payrolls** and **employees_payrolls(pivot table)** table are already connected through a many-to-many relationship and is working fine. Is it possible to fetch the **basic_pay(from positions table)** column through **positions_id** at **employees** table(which is already connected through the many-to-many relationship) so that I can perform calculation on **payroll** table that will base on **employees** basic pay?

Comment: Do you want `Position->Emplyee->Payroll;` like this?

Comment: I want to access the basic pay like this **$payroll->employees->positions->basic_pay;**

Comment: Then you have to employees id as a foreign key in your positions table

Comment: How can I implement this? It doesn't make sense to me because I think employees_id might not be necessary in positions table. Can you please explain further?

Answer (score 0):

you can not use `$payroll->employees->positions->basic_pay` because `$payroll->employees`
this gives you a collection of employees, each employee has many positions, so if you perform `$payroll->employees->positions->basic_pay` it makes collections in a collection, like below :

```
Payroll
   Employee-1
       Position-1->basic_pay
       Position-2->basic_pay  
   Employee-2
       Position-1->basic_pay
       Position-2->basic_pay
   .
   .
   .
```

if you perform `$payroll->employees->positions->basic_pay` the structure does not make sense in Laravel collection so you first perform `$payroll->employees` then loop through each and perform second loop on `$employee->positions` and next you will get `$position->basic_pay`

Comment: Of course this answer is with the structure you showed us in the picture.

Comment: Correction: In my database, an employee can only have one position. and a position can have many employees so it's a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: @SayBernaldez with that structure you can do it.

Comment: I tried it in the show.blade on payrolls and I get an error: Call to a member function pluck() on boolean.

`@foreach ($payrolls->employees as $employee)
   @foreach ($employee->positions as $position)
      {{ $position->pluck('basic_pay')->first() }}
    @endforeach
  @endforeach`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a `belongsTo` relationship in your Employee model:

```
/**
 * Get the employee's position.
 */
public function position()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Position::class,'positions_id');
}
```

Now if you wish to access it you will need to do the folllowing:

```
//get a payroll from database
$payroll = Position::find(1);

//get your payroll employees then iterate through each one
foreach($payroll->employees as $employee) {

           //access to this employee position attributes
            $employee->position;

       }
```

Comment: I already added a belongsTo relationship to a Position in my Employees Model. And about accessing the basic_pay, does that mean I have to put the foreach operation in my blade or in my controller?

Comment: Depends on where you want to do the operation, the `foreach` will work on both.

Comment: I already did that and it works but, I want to access employees **basic_pay** through Payrolls table which is somehow distant to Positions table, that's the only problem that I have.